# $project query in MongoDB with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Given this document:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5a4ea040825de6c0bbbcc810"),
"onOpened" : [ 
        {
            "createdOn" : ISODate("2018-01-04T21:46:56.756Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a4ea0d0825de6c0bbbcc828")
        }, 
        {
            "createdOn" : ISODate("2018-01-04T21:57:24.939Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a4ea344a7513e0d27642494")
        }, 
        {
            "createdOn" : ISODate("2018-01-05T18:27:26.839Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a4fc38e62a06a8cced22657")
        }]
"onSynched" : [ 
        {
            "createdOn" : ISODate("2018-01-04T21:46:56.756Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a4ea0d0825de6c0bbbcc828")
        }, 
        {
            "createdOn" : ISODate("2018-01-04T21:57:24.939Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a4ea344a7513e0d27642494")
        }, 
        {
            "createdOn" : ISODate("2018-01-05T18:27:26.839Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a4fc38e62a06a8cced22657")
        }]
```

I am trying to do an `aggregate` query in MongoDB/Mongoose so that I can select only elements from a given date range. I tried this:

```
module.exports.getWorksetStats = function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    var from = new Date(req.query.from);
    var to = new Date(req.query.to);
    HealthRecords
        .aggregate(
            [
                {$match: {_id: id}},
                {$project: {
                    'onOpened': {$filter: {
                        input: '$onOpened',
                        as: 'item',
                        cond: {$and: [
                            {$gte: ['$$item.createdOn', from]},
                            {$lte: ['$$item.createdOn', to]}
                        ]}
                    }}
                }}
            ]
        ).exec(function (err, response){
            var result = {
                status: 200,
                message: response
            };
            if (err){
                result.status = 500;
                result.message = err;
            } else if (!response){
                result.status = 404;
                result.message = err;
            }
            res.status(result.status).json(result.message);
        });
};
```

Unfortunately that seems to be returning an empty array. Can anyone think of what am I doing wrong here?

Also, the goal is to do a few things here in a single query, but I thought I can start with this. The idea is really to:
1. get `onOpened` filtered by date range, 
2. `onSynched` filtered by date range, 
3. and another collection but with a `$slice: -1`.

I am using MongoDB 3.4.7 and Mongoose 4.5.5.

Comment: why are you not eliminating in match stage?

Comment: @konrad, your query is just fine. I added sample data to my local, and ran this test query `db.collection.aggregate([
{$match: {_id: ObjectId("5a4ea040825de6c0bbbcc810")}}, {$project: {
'onOpened': {$filter: {
 input: '$onOpened',
               as: 'item',
                        cond: {$and: [
                            {$gte: ['$$item.createdOn', ISODate("2018-01-04T21:57:24.939Z")]},
{$lte: ['$$item.createdOn', ISODate("2018-01-05T18:27:26.839Z")]}
                   ]}
               }}
        }}
])
`, getting proper output. I guess problem is with your javascript part.

Comment: Ha! You are right. The issue was the that `aggregate` doesn't accept ids in a form of a string which is exactly what I was matching against doing `id = req.params.id` and what you did above is convert it to mongose `ObjectId`. I missed that. Other queries with Mongoose work just fine without converting to ObjectId

Comment: How would I apply project to both arrays: onSynched and onOpened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
db.getCollection('TEST').aggregate([{
        $match: {
            _id: id
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            onOpened: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$onOpened",
                    as: "item",
                    cond: {
                        $gte: ['$$item.createdOn', from],
                        $lte: ['$$item.createdOn', to]
                    }
                }
            },
            onSynched: 1
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Yeah! That will work. I can also apply the same filter rules to the other parts of the array. Thanks!

Comment: Please note the comment above that `id` needs to be a mongoose object.